# what does error "mysqlinsert E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!" means?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, database-connection, android-studio-4.0

I try to run my android application but gives the error: "mysqlinsert E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!". What does it means? How can I overcome it?

Comment: can you include more details? seems odd that an android app will connect directly to mysql, so many things can go wrong, you should talk to a server that talks to mysql instead. Also why the tag for android studio 2.2? You can't seriously be using that old version.

Comment: Android studio version-4 is used. And android app connect with local database.(XAMPP)

Comment: when you say local, do you mean you're running mysql inside the phone? that's what `localhost` means - which I think it's impossible unless it's a chromebook. Otherwise it's a terrible idea. And still, we need lots more details. What's your gradle dependencies and what does you code looks like?